# .Net restore getting wrong absolute path

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore, rider

I have a project that is in a zip that was originally coded on a windows 7 OS.I have since moved to windows 10 and I am trying to continue working on the project on my Windows 10 PC.
The issue is that somehow the path is still set as old path and as a result the build fails.

> Failed to read NuGet.Config due to unauthorized access. Path:
> 'C:\Users\abc\RiderProjects\myproject\NuGet.Config'. --->
> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\Users\abc\RiderProjects\myproject' is denied.

The path `C:\Users\abc\RiderProjects\myproject` should be `C:\Users\xyz\RiderProjects\myproject`.I looked within the project if i can find hardcoded references to the old path but in vain but i can see references to old path in `/bin` and `/obj` folder.

I already tried the following:

1.Look for hardcoded references to old path within solution directory

2.Clean solution

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the following to fix the issue in that specific order.

1.Remove `obj` and `bin` folders from every project.A proper gitignore file should be added before commiting to a git repository.In my case since I got the project in a zip , there was some `obj` file in some projects in the solution

2.Clean the solution

3.Rebuild the project